# How to find out if a user is granted to pg_write_all_data?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, postgresql-15, postgresql-16

Starting with PostgreSQL 14 there is a new predefined `pg_write_all_data`. To add a user to this role we use

```sql
GRANT pg_write_all_data TO our_user;
```

But how can we find out which user we granted this role in the past?